# Why Picasso library is not working in my project

Tags: android, picasso

I am try to do Picasso Gallery using Picasso in Android. Here is my code, which is not working

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(all_images[0]).into(image);
```

Manifest code

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Gradle.app file

```
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Can someone tell me why I cant see images

Comment: Show your error log.

Comment: I do not have any error in log

Comment: Then what problem you are facing. Explain clearly.

Comment: all_images[0] what is this returning?

Comment: Show the full file in which you are using Picasso .

Comment: It does not display any images

Comment: I am not first time user of android, so please do not consider such simple errors

Comment: Where you get image? from Network, disk, or internet?

Comment: I get image from Internet

Comment: Check your image url all_images[0].

Comment: what is the return type of all_images[0] ? If it contains heavy images then it should me resized.

Comment: May you show more your code?

Comment: I think it should past some time to download images, because now it works)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to your Internet connection. I realized that it should pass some time to download image from URLs with my internet speed, but code works well. So, my conclusion is be patient and do some stuff in case of no Internet connection or something like this

Answer (score 3):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` should be define outside of `<application>` tag

Check below code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

To detect error you can add callback while using Picasso, You can find below reference example

```
 Picasso.with(mContext).load(fileImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.draw_detailed_view_display)
                .error(R.drawable.draw_detailed_view_display)
                .resize(200, 200)
                .into(holder.mImageEvidence, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        holder.mMediaEvidencePb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        holder.mErrorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: can you share the value of all_images[0] ? @AssetBekbossynov

Comment: private static final String[] all_images = {
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/23/Pablo_Picasso%2C_1901-02%2C_Femme_au_caf%C3%A9_%28Absinthe_Drinker%29%2C_oil_on_canvas%2C_73_x_54_cm%2C_Hermitage_Museum%2C_Saint_Petersburg%2C_Russia.jpg",
            "https://www.vanartgallery.bc.ca/the_exhibitions/images/picasso.jpg",
            "http://www.artribune.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Pablo-Picasso-Nature-morte-aux-tulipes.jpg",
            "http://www.wantaghschools.org/cms/lib05/NY01001016/Centricity/Domain/417/picasso-two-girls-reading.jpg"
    };

Comment: Please paste your code into https://paste.ofcode.org/ and give me link @AssetBekbossynov

Comment: Thank you for try, but it works now. Can you tell me should it pass some time to download images from url??

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov You need to add URL and if it is valid then image would be shown up on ImageView. Try to use .placeholder and .error so you can easily know the problem.

Comment: @AssetBekbossynov If it does help you then you can mark it as a answer so it would be useful for others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your URLs.

Only Valid urls with images will be loaded by Picasso

The URLs You Provided are Invalid and Gave 404 Not found Error.

Try some Valid URLs